# Rails AR cannot update NULL datetime field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.1.  I have a database column t.datetime "end_at".  If I enter a date at the time of object creation, then I can change the value (update) later.  But If I leave it blank (NULL), I found that I cannot update it.  I verified that the name and new value of the field are in the params.  Why?

```
 def update
   begin
     model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
     model.update_attributes!(params[:my_model])
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      #something
   end
 end
```

Comment: Any errors? Any validation for `end_at`?

Comment: No errors.  I don't have any validation.  I actually have two fields "start_at" and "end_at".  If I populate "start_at" when creating the object and come back to edit the record, I can change start_at to a new date but I cannot change end_at from NULL to anything else.

Comment: could you post `params` from your log?

Comment: Parameters: {"id"=>"5327", "my_model"=>{"group"=>"Beauty", "name"=>"some", "end_at"=>"03/20/13 03:39 PM", "state"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save", "utf8"=>"?"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure two things are true:

- your `params[:end_at]` must contain a nil or a DateTime. Normally params do not come in as datetime.
- your column should not be a TIMESTAMP (but this is probably not the case already)

Also investigate multiparameter attributes.

Comment: It was the validation.  It gets saved when I used update_attribute which bypassed validation.  I didn't bother to convert the parameter into a DateTime object.  But why it only happens when the field is NULL, I still don't understand.  After I convert the param to a DateTime object and update the params, update_attributes works too.